# Handwritten Text Morphing of Grayscale Image

Tags: opencv3.0, scikit-image, opencv3.1, opencv, python

I would like to morph the handwritten text to better readability. I could not figure out ways to do it. For Example,

[image]

I would like to morph this Image like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to automate this process I am afraid opencv alone won't offer you a solution. You need to identify each letter then print the corresponding image or string. [Here](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/09/17/opencv-ocr-and-text-recognition-with-tesseract/) is an example.
Best of luck.

Comment: Hi @meto, I am not looking for any Deep Neural Nets approach like using a handwritten model and again writing it back to an image. I need some morphing technique that could correct the text back in shape.

Comment: The reason I suggested a DNN method is because there is no morphing technique which has the expected effect. Take a look at what cv2 offers from here then decide for yourself : https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d9/d61/tutorial_py_morphological_ops.html

Comment: Hi Meto, I know all these. There are some morphing techniques to do this. I couldn't find any implantations of it. Please refer "Smooth Morphing of Handwritten text" by Microsoft.

Comment: If you find any implementations, share with me @Meto